SSL Provider Error with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server in Laravel 11 Docker Setup
I’m encountering an SSL error when trying to connect to SQL Server using ODBC Driver 18 in a Laravel 11 application running in a Docker container with PHP and Apache. Here are the details:
Dockerfile
FROM php:8.3-apache

# Install necessary utilities for SQL Server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libpq-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    unzip \
    libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev \
    gnupg2 lsb-release \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo pdo_mysql mysqli zip bcmath intl exif pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" gd \
    && apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
    && docker-php-ext-install imap \
    && apt-get install -y libpcre3-dev \
    && pecl install apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache

# Add Microsoft repository and GPG key
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update

# Install msodbcsql18 and optional tools
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18

# Install SQL Server dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
# RUN wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb && \
#     dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y install msodbcsql18 unixodbc-dev -y
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable pdo_sqlsrv
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl \ 
    && sed -i 's,^\(MinProtocol[ ]*=\).*,\1'TLSv1.0',g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && sed -i 's,^\(CipherString[ ]*=\).*,\1'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1',g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure Apache and mod_rewrite
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public/
RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf \
    && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


database.php Configuration:
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => env('DB_SQLSRV_HOST', 'x.x.x.x'), // SQL Server IP
    'port'     => env('DB_SQLSRV_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_SQLSRV_DATABASE', 'dbname'),
    'username' => env('DB_SQLSRV_USERNAME', 'sa'),
    'password' => env('DB_SQLSRV_PASSWORD', 'password'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'options'  => [
        // 'TrustServerCertificate' => true,
        'trust_server_certificate' => false,
        'Encrypt' => false,
    ],
    'encrypt' => false,
    'trust_server_certificate' => false, // Added this line
],


Error Message:
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:EE certificate key too weak] (Connection: sqlsrv, SQL: select Userinfo.Name AS Nombre, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(Checkinout.CheckTime AS DATE), 103) AS Fecha, MIN(Checkinout.CheckTime) AS Entrada, MAX(Checkinout.CheckTime AS Salida from [Checkinout] inner join [Userinfo] on [Checkinout].[Userid] = [Userinfo].[Userid] where [Checkinout].[CheckTime] between 2024-09-09 and 2024-09-14 group by [Userinfo].[Name], [CAST(Checkinout].[CheckTime] as [DATE)] order by [Userinfo].[Name] asc, CAST(Checkinout.CheckTime AS DATE))


Additionally, from an Ubuntu 22.04 server running a pure PHP application, I can successfully connect to the same SQL Server database using the following function:
public static function connectBdBascula($base)
{
    $nombreServidor = 'x.x.x.x';
    $usuario        = 'sa';
    $contrasena     = '******';
    $puerto         = 1433;

    try {
        $connectionInfo = "Database = $base; encrypt=false;";
        $db             = new PDO("sqlsrv:server = $nombreServidor; $connectionInfo", $usuario, $contrasena);

        return $db;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Ocurrió un error en la conexión. ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}


I’ve tried setting TrustServerCertificate and Encrypt both inside and outside the options array, but the error persists. How can I resolve this SSL error and successfully connect to my SQL Server?

Try 'Encrypt' => 'no' instead of 'Encrypt' => false (as indicated here).

Aside... if you docker run -it --rm php:8.3-apache cat /etc/os-release you'll notice that your image is based on Debian 12 Bookworm. apt-key add - has been deprecated since Debian 9 days, so you're probably ignoring the warnings coming from docker build. https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list is for Debian 10 kernels so you could also be downloading incompatible libraries from that repo.

What's the output of SELECT @@VERSION when executed against your SQL Server? The certificate key too weak error message suggests that it might be a very old or unpatched version that doesn't even support TLS 1.2. SQL Server 2016 and later had TLS 1.2 support built in, and there were service packs and cumulative updates to enable it for SQL Server 2008 through 2014.

To resolve the connection issue between PHP and SQL Server, I modified the base image of the container. Specifically, I added the openssl.cnf file from my local machine to the container’s /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf directory using a COPY instruction in the Dockerfile. Here is the relevant Dockerfile snippet:
COPY path/to/local/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
where the last line CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2 is changed to CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0.  This solved the problem but not the root  problem.

The result of SELECT @@VERSION; is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ). I was already able to perform SQL queries but I understand that I need to update
